# define array php in version 5.4

Tags: php

I want to define constants like this

```
    $a = 0;
    foreach ($data as $key) {
        define('SN', array($key->SN));
        define("CODE".$a, $key->Code); 
        $a++;
    }
```

It works in php 7.0
but how to define it like this in php 5.4 ?

Comment: I font think that works in 7 either since you cant redefine SN

Answer (score 2):

According to the docs at http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php its not possile to use constants with array values.

> The value of the constant. In PHP 5, value must be a scalar value (integer, float, string, boolean, or NULL). In PHP 7, array values are also accepted.

Comment: I think he wants a solution, How can he achieve it in some other way?, Perhaps work on "scope" ?

Comment: There is no solution, other than to scrape the idea of constant usage.

Comment: Somebody said to me "nothing is impossible to achieve in programming" ... I guess he was wrong then